# jQuery Autocomplete: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

My first time using JQuery. Trying to use Autocomplete, and keep getting the error above.
I've tested the MySQL queries and they all work. 
If I use the same code below but called from a webpage without the Autocomplete code,
the JSON looks well-formed.
Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

```
<?php
$docname=$_POST['docselect'];
$surname=$_POST['lastname1'];
if (isset($_POST['lastname1'])){
    $return_arr = array();
try {
    $dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','gotlibc_testuser','**passwordgoeshere**','gotlibc_robo2')     or die("Error connecting to MySQL server.");

$query="SELECT PT_ID, surname, firstname, jnum FROM patients WHERE surname LIKE '$surname%' ORDER BY surname";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Error querying database.');

$row=array();
while($Xrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $row['label']="{$Xrow['surname']},{$Xrow['firstname']},{$Xrow['jnum']}";
   $row['value']=$Xrow['PT_ID'];
  $return_arr[]=$row;
}
}
// end try
catch(Exception $e ) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> alert('Hi'); </script>";
printf("catch activated"); 
echo $e->errorMessage();
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
mysqli_close($dbc);
}
?>
```

Here's the relevant snippets of the calling web page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#lastname1" ).autocomplete({
              source: "pt_autoshow1.php", minLength: 1
});
});
</script>

<h2>Patient Information:</h2>
<br>
<form id="surnamepicker" action="#" method="post"> or Last name: <input name="lastname1" id="lastname1" type="text">
    <div class="rage_button_781076"> <a href="">New Patient</a> </div>
 with Dr.
  <select name="docname">
    <option value="2">Doctor A</option>
    <option value="1">Doctor B</option>
    <option value="3">Doctor C</option>
  </select></form>
```

Comment: can you post the json response when calling the page independently?

Comment: [{"value":"2","label":"Smith,Adele,77776543”},{"value":"4","label":"Watson,Wendy,99876543"},{"value":"5","label":"Wilkowitz,Ida,44556677"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its working fine for me
php function will return the rows/No Results as response

```
    public function shamsearchJSON ()
    {
     $search = $this->input->post('search');

    $query = $this->user_model->getmessages($search);

        if(!empty($query)){
        echo json_encode(array('responses'=> $query));
        }
        else{
        echo json_encode(array('responses'=> 'No Results'));
        }
}
```

javascript code

```
    $( "#search-inbox" ).autocomplete({
              minLength: 2,
              source: function( request, response ) {
                //  $.getJSON( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/shamsearchJSON?search="+request.term,response );

                        $.ajax({
                          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/user/shamsearchJSON",
                          data: {"search": request.term},
                          type:"POST",
                          success: function( data ) {

                           var parsed = JSON.parse(data);

                           if(parsed.responses == "No Results")
                           {
                           alert("no results::");
                           var newArray = new Array(1);
                           var newObject = {
                                        sub: "No Results",
                                        id: 0
                                    };

                           }
                           else{
                                var newArray = new Array(parsed.length);
                                var i = 0;
                                parsed.responses.forEach(function (entry) {
                                    var newObject = {
                                        sub: entry.subject,
                                        id: entry.mID
                                    };
                                    newArray[i] = newObject;
                                    i++;
                                });

                            }
                            response(newArray);
                         },
                          error:function(){
                          alert("Please try again later");
                          }
                        });  

                },
              focus: function( event, ui ) {
                //$( "#search-inbox" ).val( ui.item.sub );
                return false;
              },
              select: function( event, ui ) {
              if(ui.item.id != 0){
                $( "#search-inbox" ).val( ui.item.sub );
                openInboxMessage(ui.item.id);
                }
                else
                {

                }
                return false;
              }
            }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ){
              return $( "<li>" ).append("<a>" + item.sub +"</a>" ).appendTo(ul);
            };
```